# reposition overlay after zoom on map

Tags: geometry, maps, javafx-8

I am working with a map on which I put an overlay to highlight certain areas, now I want to zoom the map in and out and reposition the overlay so that it is still over the same region. The map is displayed in a JavaFX WebView and the overlay is a polygon that is drawn into a group that is in a pane on top of the WebView.

Now I am trying to calculate the correct position for the overlay, but I can't figure out how. Does someone have some experience there and maybe can point me into the right direction ?

Comment: You know the local bounds of the rectangle in the webview? Use `Node.localToParent` until you reach the common ancestor and then if neccessary aply any transformations for the group using `Node.parentToLocal`...

Comment: If I am getting you right then I guess I wasn't clear enough and you misunderstood me (or rather my faulty description). I updated the question.

Comment: Gluon has a mapping library that might help you achieve your desired outcome if you're open to using something other than a WebView. Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952625/create-a-polyline-in-gluon-maplayer).